# Keys for copy & paste in FreeBSD console

Tags: freebsd, console, clipboard

How do I copy paste text inside the FreeBSD console? I tried

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>
2. <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>

I have `FreeBSD 10.1` installed in VirualBox on a Mac.

I am selecting text with the mouse in FreeBSD console and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> expecting that selected text will be inserted in the console but nothing occurs.

[image]

Comment: The console (TTY) or a terminal emulator (like xterm)?

Comment: @jasonwryan I don't know exactly, but I think in TTY. I uploaded a screenshot

Comment: That is a TTY/console. If you have mouse selection, you should be able to `Shift-Insert` to paste...

Comment: @jasonwryan thank you, it works, and in case I already have something in the clipboard how to paste it?

Comment: @efr: If you mean a clipboard on your host machine you need to enable clipboard sharing in Virtualbox

Comment: @jasonwryan it is already enabled: in `General settings of Virtual Box - advanced - Shared Clipboard - Bidirectional`. So combination `ctrl+v` must work, but it fails.

Answer (score 2):

[Putting some of the stuff from comments here as an answers so that this question may perhaps be marked answered.]

First, select text via the mouse, then press either the middle button or `Shift-Insert` to paste.

Note that you will need the VirtualBox or VMWare guest additions to copy/paste between the host and the guest. And you'll need to enable clipboard sharing for that particular VM guest. I believe they will only work in X11, not on the console.

Comment: Just commenting here since this is the first result in Google: This does work in the raw console (ie without X11).